# Rabbitmq.config mods not being applied

Tags: rabbitmq

I've installed Erlang and RabbitMQ successfully and the RabbitMQ is running fine.  My next instructions are to open the following file
C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config for editing

Delete any contents from the rabbitmq.config file and replace with the follow:

```
 [
    {rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [8709]}]},
    {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 8710}]}]}
 ].
```

Reinstall the RabbitMQ service with C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11\sbin>rabbitmq-service.bat install

Go to Windows Services and start the RabbitMQ service
Verify the RabbitMQ ports have changed by going to http://localhost:8710/

All of this doesn't work and the only way I can pull up the Web admin tool is by going to the default http://localhost:15672 site and none of the ports have changed.

Is there another way I can make sure this port change takes place?  Is RabbitMQ getting the config from some other place other than 
    C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config?

TIA
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going into the registry and removing all registry keys under HKLM/SOFTWARE/Ericsson/Erlang/ErlSrv
Then uninstall Erlang and Rabbit and reinstall both.
This eliminated the issue I was having.